# Complex Database Query in Django Graph-Structure

Tags: sql, django, database, postgresql, performance

I have a django-project with the following model structure. At first I have a graph-structure with nodes and (directed and weighted) edges in the following way:

```python
class Node(models.Model):
    name = models.TextField()

class Edge(models.Model):
    from_node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='edge_from_node')
    to_node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING, related_name='edge_to_node')
    costs = models.IntegerField()
```

There also do exists token, whereby a node can be related to multiple tokens but a token can only be related to one node:

```python
class Token(models.Model):
    node = models.ForeignKey(Node, on_delete=models.DO_NOTHING)
```

Additional I have a User object that can own multiple tokens:

```python
class MyUser(models.Model):
    tokens = models.ManyToManyField(Token)
```

I now want to make a database query that for a given **TargetNode** and **MyUser** gives the edge with the minimal costs connecting any node, for which **MyUser** owns a token, with the TargetNode. Let me make a simple example:

```python
# we create 4 nodes ...
n1 = Node(name="node 1")
n2 = Node(name="node 2")
n3 = Node(name="node 3")
n4 = Node(name="node 4")
n1.save()
n2.save()
n3.save()
n4.save()

# -.. and create 3 edges
e1 = Edge(from_node=n2, to_node=n1, costs=3)
e2 = Edge(from_node=n3, to_node=n1, costs=2)
e3 = Edge(from_node=n4, to_node=n1, costs=1)
e1.save()
e2.save()
e3.save()

# create a user
user = MyUser()
user.save()

# create 2 tokens for the given user to node2 and node3
t1 = Token(node=n2)
t2 = Token(node=n3)
t1.save()
t2.save()
user.tokens.add(t1, t2)
```

this give the following simple structure

[image]

Defining `node1` as the target node. In this simple example there are only two nodes (`node2` and `node3`) that are connected to `node1` and the user owns a token. So there are only two edges which come into question: `edge1` and `edge2`.  Because `edge1` has `costs=3` and `edge2` has `costs=2` i would like to have `edge2`.

I already wrote a function for this purpose that is working (my code only gives the costs of the edge not the edge itself which is also ok).

```python
# get list of all nodes from where we can got to the node1
incoming_nodes = {x.from_node for x in Edge.objects.filter(to_node=n1)}

# get all nodes for which the user owns a token
nodes_with_token = {x.node for x in user.tokens.all()}

# create a empty list for saving the minimal costs
minimal_costs = []
for n in incoming_nodes.intersection(nodes_with_token):
    # add all edge costs of edges that are connecting then nodes with the target node
    minimal_costs += [y.costs for y in Edge.objects.filter(from_node=n)]

    if len(minimal_costs) == 0:
        print("there is no connecting edge")
        pass

result = min(minimal_costs)
```

but as you can see my function makes a lot of (seemingly) redundant database queries which are ok for simple applications but not if my database is scaling. So my Question: Is there a way to do this query at once or maybe somehow different then I did but more efficient?

p.s. I don't know if it is a useful information but i'm using a PostgreSQL-Database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very good improvement (still open for better/faster solutions).

```python
eligible_nodes = Node.objects.filter(from_node__to_node=target)  & Node.objects.filter(token__myuser=user)
minimal_cost_edge = Edge.objects.filter(from_node__in=eligible_nodes, to_node=target).order_by('costs')[0]
print("result new", minimal_cost_edge.costs)
```

I've timed the old version again the new version with 10000 Nodes and a user with 5000. The old version took **10.45 sec**. and the new one **0.03 sec**. So a  improvement of **351%**